# can I use Getx and Bloc state management in one project ( Social Network app , big project ) without problems?

Tags: bloc, state-management, flutter-packages, flutter-getx

My project is a Social network hybrid mobile app that is made with flutter, dart ( frontend ) and Nodejs as a backend,

the point that I hired front end developers that made part of the project ( 35 % of the project ) using GetX as state Management, then for some circumstances, I seek another developer, who told that I will use Bloc as state management,

so I told him, he can make the rest of the project ( 65 % ) in Bloc and leave the part that made before with Getx but he told me again that  using his structure in the bloc with other developers structure in Getx will cause problems in the future, so he must rebuild the app from Scratch, this option will make me forget all costs and Time taken in first parts made with getX to rebuild it again,

so please help me,  My question :

1. Can I use getx and bloc in My project without any problems happened in the future?
2. what is the best course of Action in that Case?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Despite it is a bad practice, you can use different state management or any other similar packages on one project as long as your projects architecture is complied. You can architecture your projects as modular ones, like n-tier approach.
But still it is a bad practice and harder to use BLoC and GetX in one project in my opinion.
GetX has some features and syntax which doesn't quite comply with the so called Flutter way. Most importantly the navigation system.

In summary, if your other 65% is somewhat independent with the other 35% which uses GetX, you can use BLoC without much problems.

To answer your question:

1. You can. But it's a bad practice. And if there are no certain boundary, your future devs will get confused.
2. If you already, hire the BLoC guy,then ask him to take time to learn GetX (it's quite easy to learn) and do the rest in GetX. If he can't or unwilling to do so, you can release him or in worst case, your GetX part is completely wasted.
   You can always hire a new dev like me who can do it in GetX.

Answer (score 2):

I was using provider, then BloC and finally only use GetX. As mentioned above, GetX has all the features in only one place, and also it is so easy to learn.

Hope my experience can help you.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

GetX is easy to learn and implement. You should go with GetX.